# Maintain aspect ratio of flex item with same height as parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

I have a flexbox container with two flex items. One of them is supposed to have a square aspect ratio while the other fills up the remaining width. Both of them should have the same (non-fixed) height.

The element that should be square is already square based on its content: It has equal padding on all sides and contains an element with the same fixed width and height (an icon). It should just grow to the height of the parent and grow equally in width.

Is there a non-JS solution for this problem?

I have looked at various issues around aspect ratios and flexbox but none worked out for my situation so far, including the aspect-ratio property and the padding trick.

A minimal example is this:

```css
.container {
  padding: 8px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}

.icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      X
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `align-items: start;` on the parent element keeps the square aspect ratio but it doesn't grow to the parent height anymore.